# Equivalent definition of Sobolev space.

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

I was reading a book on harmonic analysis and I found the following definiton:

If $a\in\mathbb{R}$ we define the sobolev space $L_a^2(\mathbb{R})$ as:

$$ L_a^2(\mathbb{R}^n)=\lbrace g:L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\mid (1+|\xi|^2)^{a/2}\hat{g}(\xi)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\rbrace$$

But, the definition I was used to see in the books is the following:
$$L_k^2(\mathbb{R}^n)=\lbrace g:L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\mid \partial^\alpha g\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)~\forall~|\alpha|\leq k\rbrace$$
where $k$ is a positive integer. My question is  if the first definition is equivalent to the second one in the case when $a$ is a positive integer. It must be, since otherwise it wouldn't be called sovolev space, but I don't see how to prove it.

Any help would be thanked.

Comment: Yes, they're the same. The basic idea is to use $\widehat{\partial^\alpha_xf}= c_\alpha \xi^{\alpha} \hat{f}$ to move from one definition to the other.

Comment: @Jose27 that is what I was thinking, but I can't do the details. I don't know how to relate the teerm $c_\alpha\xi^\alpha$ with $(1+|\xi|^2)^{a/2}$

Comment: The trick is to notice that $(1 + |\xi|^2)^{a/2}$ behaves like a positive constant near zero and like $|\xi|^{a}$ at infinity, so it is comparable with $1+|\xi| + \ldots + |\xi|^{a}$ on the whole space.